# Prevent writing errors in browser console after logout in Angular Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication

Issue : Currently when I log out in the application, the following error is logged in the browser console,

`core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: permission_denied at /all-posts: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
    at Object.webpackJsonp.../../../../@firebase/database/dist/cjs/src/core/util/util.js.exports.errorForServerCode (util.js:513)
    at onComplete (SyncTree.js:538)
    at Object.onComplete (Repo.js:115)
    at PersistentConnection.webpackJsonp.../../../../@firebase/database/dist/cjs/src/core/PersistentConnection.js.PersistentConnection.onListenRevoked_ (PersistentConnection.js:692)
    at PersistentConnection.webpackJsonp.../../../../@firebase/database/dist/cjs/src/core/PersistentConnection.js.PersistentConnection.onDataPush_ (PersistentConnection.js:464)
    at PersistentConnection.webpackJsonp.../../../../@firebase/database/dist/cjs/src/core/PersistentConnection.js.PersistentConnection.onDataMessage_ (PersistentConnection.js:452)
    at Connection.webpackJsonp.../../../../@firebase/database/dist/cjs/src/realtime/Connection.js.Connection.onDataMessage_ (Connection.js:262)
    at Connection.webpackJsonp.../../../../@firebase/database/dist/cjs/src/realtime/Connection.js.Connection.onPrimaryMessageReceived_ (Connection.js:256)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (Connection.js:157)
    at WebSocketConnection.webpackJsonp.../../../../@firebase/database/dist/cjs/src/realtime/WebSocketConnection.js.WebSocketConnection.appendFrame_ (WebSocketConnection.js:197)`

There are other similar errors related to permission are logged in the console, this is just for sample.
[Here is snapshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tI3U9.png)
I am trying to figure out if there is a way to prevent logging these type of errors in the browser console programmatically.

Here's my current code for logout :

```
logout() {
     this.afAuth.auth.signOut()
     .then( () => {
         this.router.navigate(['login']);
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have listeners on a Firebase Database that require the user to be authenticated. When you sign the user out, those listeners become illegal, so the Firebase Database cancels them and tells your app about the error.

To prevent this, stop the listeners before signing the user out by calling [`ref.off()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#off) for each of them.

Comment: Yes, I have listeners on the Firebase to update the data in case it changes. Thanks for suggesting `ref.off()`

Comment: I would love to upvote your answer but my current reputation is below 15, so it's allowing me to upvote any of the answers.. :(  But I have checked the checkmark..

Comment: No worries. That's just my snippet explaining the system. ;-)   The best way to get a higher reputation on Stack Overflow is to answer a few questions from others. I highly recommend doing this both for the rep, but also because it's fun!

Comment: Thanks.. I appreciate your advice.. :)